# Menu Block won't display when a page has a view block

Tags: views, blocks, 6

I have the *Menu Block* module installed to provide some contextual menus for certain areas of a site. These generally work great. But I have a few pages where I'm adding a Views generated block to the bottom of the page, and on these pages the menu block seems to ignore the fact that these pages exist in the menu system and will not show anything.

If you have experienced this before and have a solution that's fantastic. Otherwise I'm hoping for some pointers as to where to look around for potential issues.

It seems to be related to the block using the row style instead of the fields style. If I change it to fields, the *Menu Block* module works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

On Drupal 7, I used the [Menu Position](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_position) module, and set rules for the content types that were being displayed via a view. I set their parent menu item and that's it. This makes the [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module treat any view page as a normal page, and the menu block finally appeared, correctly configured.